# Tailwind CSS - Can't center search bar inside a div

Tags: html, css, reactjs, search, tailwind-css

I want to center the search bar inside the parent div but it's not working.
I tried using flex and justify-center on the parent div but not only it doesn't center, it also shrinks my search bar's div. I think it's because it is not allowed to have the classes flex nested inside each other, so I tried text-center but that also didn't work.

Some links I looked into:

1. https://tailwindcss.com/docs/justify-content
2. https://tailwindcss.com/docs/text-align

**Code:**

```
<div>
   <div className="flex items-center max-w-md shadow rounded border-0 p-3">
       <input type="search" className="flex-grow py-2" placeholder="Search by name..." />
       <i className="fas fa-search flex-grow-0 py-2 px-2" />
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: have you used content-center?

Comment: yes, i've put it inside the top div and it didn't work

Comment: your current code doesn't have anything added to the ' parent that matters ' . The outer `<div>` . Your searchbar covers the whole width of it's direct parent. Question. Do you want to be centered horrizontally , right ?

Comment: yes i want my search bar to be center horizontally inside it's parent div, and my search bar doesn't take the full width of it's parent dive because i used max-w-md on it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `max-w-md` class limits the width of the `div` to which it's applied, but it doesn't centre the `div` itself. To do that, add the `mx-auto` class:

```html
<div className="flex items-center max-w-md mx-auto shadow rounded border-0 p-3">
```

https://play.tailwindcss.com/H3C7MWgUeC